# How to make Google Assistant to read information from a file

Tags: google-assistant

How to make Google Home Assistant to read information from a file?

With one voice command I need GH to respond with a specific information from a file.
When "Hey Google, what are the consumption for water meter on October 2018" then GH must read info from a .docx file or from google .doc file

Anyone tried this?

Comment: googled `google assistant drive worksheet`  and hit this https://www.reddit.com/r/ifttt/comments/5kieg5/google_assistant_google_drive_spreadsheet_applet/ .......  it may point you in the right direction